# How often does buildmaster check changes on repository?

Tags: git, https, buildmaster

I used buildmaster to build our code automatically. Recently we started to have exceptions when buildmaster checks status of the repository, the https request looks like this,

https://user:password@company.git.cloudforge.com/repo_name.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack

Does anyone know how often buildmaster checks the repo for changes?

Comment: Link doesnt work. Also please post the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

By default, it polls every 1 minute. You can see (and change) this value if you look for the **ScheduleExecuterThrottle** setting in Administration > All Settings.